# Where can I find really old versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, phoenix, firebird

I am looking for an old version of Mozilla Firefox from before it was called Firefox.

It used to be called Mozilla Phoenix before it was ever called Mozilla Firebird.

I am looking for some of the oldest versions around (for Win32).  Where can I find them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Firefox Releases](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/releases/): Scroll down for older versions. Phoenix 0.1 is the oldest release available here.

[Directory of Phoenix Releases](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/phoenix/releases/): A download location for Phoenix 0.1 through 0.5.

Comment: That only shows the release notes, no (old) downloads at all.

Comment: @Arjan: The downloads are there.  Click on any version number link, then click on the **download and installation instructions** link you'll find on that page.  For instance, here's the link to version 0.1 of Phoenix: http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/releases/0.1.html#install

Comment: Ok, not for *all* versions then. For most release notes the links refer to either http://www.getfirefox.com/ or http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all.html

Answer (score 4):

For older versions of any browser you can go to [browsers.evolt.org](http://browsers.evolt.org/).

Answer (score 1):

[**oldversion.com**](http://www.oldversion.com/Mozilla-Firefox.html) has older version for Firefox. Not sure it goes far enough for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for some of the oldest
>   versions around (for Win32). Where can
>   I find them?

here is THE oldest version around ((for win32), Phoenix 0.1:

[direct download link](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/phoenix/releases/0.1/phoenix-0.1-win32.zip)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for old versions [to run on Mac OS 9](http://www.everymac.com/articles/q&a/macos-9-classic-support/faq/web-browsers-for-macos-9-classic-icab-netscape.html), there's actually a new version of Mozilla being actively developed: [Classilla](http://www.classilla.org/), with version 9.1 [planned](http://code.google.com/p/classilla/wiki/Roadmap) for March 15, 2010.