# Downgrade Firefox

Tags: firefox, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find really old versions of Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/65658/where-can-i-find-really-old-versions-of-firefox)

How can I clearly downgrade Firefox?

Particularly,need 3.5 version.

Seems that 3.6 has some problems with Firebug for me.

Links for official site downloading page goes to latest 3.6 version any way.

Comment: Ensure you are using the latest (V1.5) Firebug... it didn't prompt me to update so I just installed the latest version manually without problem.

Comment: @sergionni: Better to wait on this to be closed and moved automatically.

Comment: And this question has a duplicate here: http://superuser.com/questions/65658/where-can-i-find-really-old-versions-of-firefox

Answer (score 6):

You can download Firefox 3.5.7 in the [older downloads section](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/all-older.html) of the Firefox download page.

Answer (score 1):

i am using firefox 3.6 and it still work with firebug 1.5.

the solutions for downgrade the firefox, you should uninstall the firefox and then you could get old version from filehippo.com